# What is "Hitman: Sniper Challenge"?

Tags: steam, hitman-absolution

I recently bought Hitman: Absolution on Steam and noticed that I got 2 new games: Hitman: Absolution and also some other game called "Hitman: Sniper Challenge".

What is this "Hitman: Sniper Challenge," and how did I get this in my Steam library?

Comment: Honestly, this information can be found easily with a quick Google search. Or you could just click the "Store Page" button while looking at it in your Steam library. And why not just play the game and find out?

Comment: @murgatroid99 While this answer could be found with a quick Google.com search, many people are afraid of viruses and malware that can be obtained by going on unknown sites. Stackexchange.com is a site where I can get answers to my questions without risking infection of my computer. Not everyone knows that there is some "Store" button. Half the questions on Stackexchange could be answered with a Google.com search. Not everyone wishes to use that website, however.

Comment: @avestar101 That's one of the more interesting excuses I've read to justify lack of research.  Run Adblock and Noscript.  Or, alternatively, run the game and see what it does.

Comment: @avestar101 You asked a question about a Steam game. The answer I posted is from *Steam*. If you go into your Steam library, choose "Hitman: Sniper Challenge", and click "Store Page", you get the page that I got my answer from. The first Google hit for the search 'What is this "Hitman: Sniper Challenge"?' is that same page on Steam website. There is absolutely no excuse here for doing that bare minimum of research.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You cannot claim that this question is invalid because I did not do research: you don't *have* to do research before asking a question on this website. I did go to the Steam page, and it told me about the game, but not about how it magically appeared in my library. I am afraid that my computer may have been hacked, and the game is a virus. Perhaps I should re-word my question.

Comment: No, it's a valid question; there are no close votes on it.  Doesn't mean you can't expect downvotes for demonstrating a rather obvious lack of effort, though.

Comment: @avestar101 The Steam page *does* say how it magically appeared in your library: quote from the Steam page: "Notice: Sniper Challenge is available to Pre-Purchasers of Hitman Absolution." You are correct that research is not *required* to ask a question here, which is why it's not close, but the first part of the downvote description is "This question does not show any research effort", which is why this question is getting downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Steam store page for the game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/205930), *Hitman: Sniper Challenge* comes with preorders for *Hitman: Absolution*. The game description on the store page says:

> Get ready to pull the trigger on a completely new chapter in the award-winning Hitman series. Be the ultimate assassin in the Hitman Sniper Challenge by testing your reactions, focus and skill in a stand-alone hit available only for Hitman Absolution pre-purchases. Unlock weapons and upgrades that can be carried over into HITMAN: ABSOLUTION and compare your scores with other players around the globe using online leaderboards.
>
> HITMAN: SNIPER CHALLENGE has been created as a standalone experience to reward fans who pre-purchase HITMAN: ABSOLUTION.
>
> From a balcony overlooking a roof-top party, you are tasked with taking out Richard Strong, Jr., CEO of Stallion Armaments, along with his entire staff of bodyguards. Skilled players will capitalize on score multipliers, discover secret extras, unlock equipment upgrades, and marvel at the many creative ways to discretely dispose of a body while they work to fulfil their contract in the most efficient way possible.